# i want to fetch employee_id from employees table which is not a forgein_key when a user logged in fields are same user

Tags: mysql, laravel-9

I want to fetch `employee_id` from the employee's table which is not a forgein_key and designation from the same table when a user logs in both fields are the same user

```
public function create()
{
    $approvelsystem = Approvelsystem::all();
    $campuses = Campus::all();
    $categories = Category::where('status', '1')->get();

    // Retrieve the currently logged-in user
    $employee = Employee::where('email', Auth::user()->email)->first();

    return view('admin.demand.create', compact('approvelsystem', 'campuses', 'categories', 'employee'));
}
```

this is my controller function

Answer (score 0):

In this code, we first check if the `$employee` object exists, and if it does, we extract the `employee_id` and `designation` fields. We then pass these values to the view using `compact`. Make sure to update your view accordingly to display these values as needed.

```
public function create()
{
    $approvelsystem = Approvelsystem::all();
    $campuses = Campus::all();
    $categories = Category::where('status', '1')->get();

    // Retrieve the currently logged-in user
    $employee = Employee::where('email', Auth::user()->email)->first();

    // Check if the employee exists
    if ($employee) {
        $employee_id = $employee->employee_id;
        $designation = $employee->designation;
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the employee doesn't exist if needed.
        $employee_id = null;
        $designation = null;
    }

    return view('admin.demand.create', compact('approvelsystem', 'campuses', 'categories', 'employee_id', 'designation'));
}
```

Now you can directly access `employee_id` and `designation` in your view file.